# R tells me I'm missing a dependency package when I'm not?

Tags: r

I have a handful of R scripts that I routinely run every day so all of the necessary packages have been running just fine for months. Yesterday I installed the RInno package and I believe this has somehow affected other packages because my routine scripts no longer run due to the inability to load my normal packages.

When troubleshooting I started with the odbc package. When trying to load it gives me:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘odbc’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>   there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

I then ran `.libPaths()`, checked both of the returned paths, and the Rcpp package existed in both.

I've even tried re-installing both odbc and Rcpp with no luck. Does anyone know what could be going on here?

**Update1:** While trying to re-install Rcpp did not work, re-installing dplyr did manage to fix the missing rlang issue. So I decided to go download Rcpp directly from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html and then paste it manually into both of my library folders. This seems to have fixed the Rcpp issue but I am now met with the following new error when trying to load odbc or run `devtools::session_info()`:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : object 'vI' not found

**Update2:** Ultimately I decided to do a restore on my two library folders to a time before I installed RInno and it seems to have worked. I still have no idea what RInno did but I won't be trying that again.

Comment: Instead of checking .libPaths() what happens if you try to load Rcpp directly? `library(Rcpp)`

Comment: `Error in library(Rcpp) : there is no package called ‘Rcpp’`

Comment: can you post your ``devtools::session_info()`` in your question please?

Comment: I can't even run that! `Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘rlang’`

Comment: Might I also add that all of these packages that are "missing", their folders were all edited yesterday at the time I installed RInno. I have no idea what that package did to them because trying to re-install them doesn't work.

Comment: I used to get that error when using ``dyplr``, if you are using this package, can you try ``install.packages("dplyr")`` ? Edit : saw your comment, seems like Rlnno really did something during the installation.

Comment: `'\\termna.local\Shares\User Shares\Documents'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
'\\termna.local\Shares\USERSH~1\DOCUME~1\R\R-35~1.2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status` This was from trying to install dplyr.

Comment: Update: While trying to re-install Rcpp did not work, re-installing dplyr did manage to fix the missing rlang issue. So I decided to go download Rcpp directly from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html and then paste it manually into both of my library folders. This seems to have fixed the Rcpp issue but I am now met with the following new error when trying to load odbc or run `devtools::session_info()`: `Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  object 'vI' not found`

Comment: I also can't remove it even though it's there `Error in remove.packages : there is no package called ‘odbc’`

Comment: @KyleDixon:  you should not paste a package directly into your library folder.  Use `install.packages("/path/to/pkg.zip", type = "binary", repos = NULL)` (with the right path and zip file name).

Comment: Ultimately I decided to do a restore on my two library folders to a time before I installed RInno and it seems to have worked. I still have no idea what RInno did but I won't be trying that again.